# Android - exceptions when trying to display a list with multiple columns

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I had a list with one column which worked with an adapter, and it worked. Now I am trying to make it into two columns, and I am getting exceptions.

I am following this tutorial which seems to be the simplest: http://www.heikkitoivonen.net/blog/2009/02/15/multicolumn-listview-in-android/

I have a Java Activity that I declare like this:

```
public class SeeAllQuestionsActivity extends ListActivity
```

and here is a bit of code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FlurryAgent.onStartSession(this, "8CA5LTZ5M73EG8R35SXG");

    setContentView(R.layout.all_question_page);
...
```

Here is the all_question_page xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="3px"
        >

<include android:id="@+id/header"
         layout="@layout/header"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>    

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/loading_questions" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Some prompt text."
    android:textSize="10sp"
    />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="@+id/label"
        android:textSize="20px" >        
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

By the way, if someone can explain to me the diffrence between two syntaxes for referencing the list id, it would be great:

```
  android:id="@android:id/list"  
  android:id="@+id/list"
```

FYI, neither of these is working for me :)

And here is the questions_list.xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:paddingTop="4dip"
     android:paddingBottom="6dip"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="horizontal">

     <TextView android:id="@+id/TRAIN_CELL"
         android:layout_width="50dip"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

     <TextView android:id="@+id/FROM_CELL"
         android:layout_width="70dip"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1"/>

     <TextView android:id="@+id/TO_CELL"
         android:layout_width="60dip"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

When I run this on the simulator, it crashes with a runtime exception complaining about this line: `setContentView(R.layout.all_question_page);` and the error is:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
```

Please help, I am pretty stuck

Thank you!!

Comment: When you set up the list in your code did you set up the array of integers for the adapter and the corresponding R.id.TRAIN_CELL, R.id.FROM_CELL,  and R.id.TO_CELL?

Comment: @HowardHodson I didn't set it up before the setContentView call. Should I have done that? I didn't notice the tutorial doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference seems to be that the former is what you'd need to use in order to use a ListActivity and the latter is what you'd use if you weren't going to use ListActivity, but instead just a normal Activity. So you'll have to stick with. (Note: I've never personally used ListActivity, so I can't exactly vouch for this)

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

I would also suggest removing these too lines from your ListView:

```
android:text="@+id/label"
android:textSize="20px"
```

Neither text, nor textSize are valid attributes of [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html). And for any widget that text is a valid attribute of I don't think you'd ever want to set the text equal to something like `"@+id/label"`. If you are trying to reference a string from your strings.xml file you'd need to use `"@string/label"`. Referencing an id like that for the text will put some hex code into the text that will have no meaning to the user(if it works at all).

It is possible that removing those might fix your trouble, if so my guess is that having the text set to another id was confusing something into thinking that your list didn't have the id `list`

If that does not solve your problem I would suggest switching to a plain Activity instead of ListActivity and getting the reference to your ListView via `findViewById()` like they do in the example that you linked.

Comment: thanks, trying it now...one thing is that when I extended Activity instead of ListActivity, lines like this ListView list = getListView(); started giving syntax errors because they are part of ListActivity ....and I needed that object because later in the code I do this  lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()  which listens when the user presses one of the list items.

Comment: When I took out those two lines you mentioned and I still get the same error.

Comment: Got it to work after implementing your advice - thank you! :)

Comment: to make it more clear for people in the future, did you manage to get it working with ListActivity? or did you end up switching to normal Activity?

Comment: I got it to work with just extending Activity.  But actually this caused another error later where I have something like text_view_object_that_was_instantiated_earlier.setVisibility(View.GONE); and it throws a null pointer exception on the return of a remote Asynch call....any clue why that may be the case?

Comment: nope, sounds like a separate problem though. If you are still facing that post it as a new question.

Comment: I just posted the new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11630942/android-having-trouble-updating-a-listadapter-after-an-asynch-call  thank you for your help..really appreciate it.