# Android - having trouble updating a ListAdapter after an Asynch call

Tags: android, android-layout, android-asynctask

I am setting up a ListView adapter like this:

```
public class SeeAllQuestionsActivity extends Activity
{
    //ArrayAdapter<Question> adapter;   
    SimpleAdapter mSchedule = null;
    ListView list = new ListView (this);

    TextView loading_questions = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        
        setContentView(R.layout.all_question_page);

        TextView loading_questions = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.loading_questions);

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        mSchedule = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist, R.layout.questions_list,
                new String[] {"train", "from", "to"}, 
                new int[] {R.id.TRAIN_CELL, R.id.FROM_CELL, R.id.TO_CELL});

        list.setAdapter(mSchedule);

        list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
        {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) 
            {              
              ...
```

and then making a remote Asynch call to get the list from my database, and trying to do this in the onPostExecute method:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    try
                    {
                        JSONArray obj = new JSONArray(result);

                        if ( obj != null )
                        {

                            for ( int i = 0; i < obj.length(); i++ )
                            {
                                JSONObject o = obj.getJSONObject(i);

                                map.put("train", "Business Name");
                                map.put("from", ">");
                                map.put("to", ">");
                                mylist.add(map);
                                map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                                map.put("train", "103(x)");
                                map.put("from", "6:35 AM");
                                map.put("to", "7:45 AM");
                                mylist.add(map);                                                                    
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch ( Exception e )
                    {
                    }                   

                    list.setAdapter(mSchedule);
```

but I get a Null Pointer exception on this line:

```
ListView list = new ListView (this);
```

But I think generally I am way off in how this needs to be done in the postExecute method.  Any help with how to do this correctly is much appreciated.

Comment: Your line `ListView list = new ListView (this);` is not necessary. You defined your ListView in the XML and you can assign it to a variable like you already did: `list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);`

Comment: @MartijnVanMierloo oh right, good point. I am going to try this now, but I think my code after the server returns is still a bit of a mess....regardless...trying with your suggestion now.

Comment: @MartijnVanMierloo your suggestion definitely prevented the crashing, but there is still a problem in that the screen does not end up displaying the lists that I set.

Comment: Are you sure the `result` is not null?

Comment: @MartijnVanMierloo yes 100% confident result is not null because I use this backend code all the time, plus this code used to work when I had the listview in a different way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **OnCreate** you define a new SimpleAdapter and attach it to your ListView. This is correct. The datasource (`mylist` in your case) is empty at this point so you will fill it with in an `AsyncTask`.

In your **onPostExecute** you are creating a new `ArrayList`. Depending on the result you receive, you fill it. After you did this, you are setting the adapter again. Which will do nothing because the adapter has no data.. What you want to do, is give your new filled list to your Adapter so it can fill the `ListView` with your data.

**Solution 1**

```
onPostExecute {
   // create a list to store your data
   new ArrayList

   // fill the new list with the data you received (result)
   fillArrayList from JSON

   // create an adapter and give the new list with it
   mAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(.., ArrayList, ...)
   listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);   
}
```

This is one way you can do it and fits you current implementation.

**Solution 2**

I would opt for this solution

```
onPostExecute {
    // don't create a new arraylist but use the mylist-object you created in the OnCreate
    fill mylist object with new data 

    // mylist is the datasource of your adapter and it is now changed.
    // let the ListView know his adapter received new information
    mSchedule.notifyDataSetChanged
}
```

**UPDATE**

Check out [this tutorial](http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2010/01/03/android-simple-listview-using-simpleadapter/). I use the same layouts and same source to fill my list but I have altered it so it is similar to your case. Good luck :)

*MainActivity*

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private List<HashMap<String, String>> fillMaps;
    private SimpleAdapter adapter;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

        String[] from = new String[] { "rowid", "col_1", "col_2", "col_3" };
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.item1, R.id.item2, R.id.item3, R.id.item4 };

        // My data
        fillMaps = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Create an adapter which will tell my ListView what to show..
        // fillMaps is still empty so at the moment it my ListView will show
        // nothing.
        adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, fillMaps, R.layout.row, from, to);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Retreive data from somewhere
        new UpdateListWithAsyncTask().execute();
    }

    private class UpdateListWithAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // do stuff
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // Fill your datasource that your adapter has. In my case fillMaps
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("rowid", "" + i);
                map.put("col_1", "col_1_item_" + i);
                map.put("col_2", "col_2_item_" + i);
                map.put("col_3", "col_3_item_" + i);
                fillMaps.add(map);
            }

            // my datasource is now changed, I want my adapter to know this and
            // update my ListView
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes the second solution you suggest looks very good. I am a bit confused about how it works though since the mSchedule is just the map and not the list.  I am trying it now...I commented out the list.setAdapter(mSchedule);  and added mSchedule.notifyDataSetChanged();  after I set the data.  Trying it now..

Comment: In the code you showed in your question, is `mSchedule` the adapter of your `ListView`

Comment: yes, mSchedule is defined to be the SimpleAdapter like this      mSchedule = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist, R.layout.questions_list,
                new String[] {"train", "from", "to"}, 
                new int[] {R.id.TRAIN_CELL, R.id.FROM_CELL, R.id.TO_CELL});

Comment: I just ran the code and the list didn't get populated. :(   ...I think we are not notifying the mSchedule that the map is different.  I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: Are you still creating a new ArrayList inside your `OnPostExecute`?

Comment: I think I am missing something like this from the original code: mSchedule = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist, R.layout.questions_list,
                new String[] {"train", "from", "to"}, 
                new int[] {R.id.TRAIN_CELL, R.id.FROM_CELL, R.id.TO_CELL}); ...but I am not sure how to do this correctly here, espcially since the "this" keyword may not quite be appropriate in this case.

Comment: Create a membervariable mylist.. Use that one to give with your adapter as parameter AND fill with data in your onPostExecute. When it is filled, you can let the adapter know by calling the notifyDataSetChanged and the ListView will fill itself :)

Comment: Martijn Van Mierloo hmmm, but I think I do exactly that. I already create the        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>(); and then I add things to it, and after I finish adding things to it, I do  mSchedule.notifyDataSetChanged();  but it isn't happening for me.

Comment: if it is ok, would you be able to show in code how that would look like so it might be easier for me to spot the place where I am going wrong? Thank you for your help - much appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for the write-up - I am trying this out right now :)

Comment: thank you - this worked!!! If you would like, I have a bounty on this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11533819/android-how-to-align-list-view-items-to-be-nicely-spaced-left-and-right-align#11533859 you can post an answer with the link to this question and I would be happy to give you the bounty reward. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

As i remember and as a logical conclusion: In the moment of your call the reference of **this** is **null**. **this** will be accessed in the constructor of your **ListView** thus a **NullPointerException** will be raised. If you want to create it dynamically you have to call the **ListView** constructor within the **onCreate** method of your **Activity**.

At least it's better to implement it as suggested by MartijnVanMierloo, if possible.

Comment: I just commented out the line with the "this" and have this line in onCreate: list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);   ... but I still can't get the list items to show up on the screen when the program returns from the asynch call. Any idea why not?